# How to wrap text along an image?

Tags: css

[image: Snap1: it is okey[![Snap2: A very long word comes next (in the next line)to the image]

How to make this long word(a part of the word) appear along the image in the same line? I have tried:

```
<div style="width:200;background:#00FFFF;word-wrap:break-word;">
 <img src="1.png">ThisIsAveryVeryVeryLongWordNextToTheImage
</div>
```

Comment: @Aziz why did you change the original code?

Comment: I made it a stack snippet, what's the issue? It's still the same, just more clear.

Comment: @Aziz You added `px` next to `200` That's the argument going below. Check.

Comment: It's a minor syntax error and does not affect the question's subject - our job as a community is to reduce confusion.

Comment: @Aziz At the same time we need to make it clear to the OP that it is wrong. But the OP denies, `it should be width:200px, but browsers do well with this too` and I have also added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: nowrap`:

```
<div style="width:200px;background:#00FFFF;word-wrap:break-word;white-space: nowrap;">
  <img src="1.png">ThisIsAveryVeryVeryLongWordNextToTheImage
</div>
```

Also use `width: 200px` as `width:200` is invalid in CSS.

**Updated**

```html
<div style="width: 200px; background: #00FFFF; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;">
  <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />ThisIsAveryVeryVeryLongWordNextToTheImage
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks,but this makes part of the text appear outside the container div which is not expected.

Comment: @rosemary Having something like `Long text text text tex...` would be better?

Comment: I got your point,but eager to know if there is too long word,then what would be the solution.

Comment: @rosemary Yea, that's what I asked. Truncate it and give ellipsis `...` at the end. You can use: `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` Lemme update my answer with a preview.

Comment: @rosemary See the updated answer, please. You have a preview as well.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have one vote for you,however I have tried a different solution ,you can check in my answer

Comment: @rosemary There's still errors in your code. You have `width: 200`, that's a syntax error, and my solution is totally different. Upto you. :)

Comment: How is this a valid answer? The image and the text are **not** in the same line...

Comment: @Aziz Ah... I just checked that. Updated. My mistake. I saw the pic in the OP. Can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width:200;background:#00FFFF;word-wrap:break-word;word-break: break-all">
  <img src="1.png">  ThisIsAveryVeryVeryLongWordNextToTheImage
</div>
```

Comment: This is not valid. The `width:200` is invalid. Check my answer.

Comment: I got it friend, it should be width:200px, but browsers do well with this too

Comment: Chrome 50 (latest) on your code: http://i.imgur.com/zj7CoIv.png I am sure [CSS Spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/width) says you **need** to put `px`.

Comment: @rosemary do you want the container to have a fixed width or it doesn't matter? Please clarify.

Comment: the container should have fixed width